# How do I reuse my server-side Facebook access_token in javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

**Scenario/setup**

I have a web application that allows a user to log in using either Facebook or username+password. The user is able to link Facebook to the account, in which case the backend stores an offline Facebook access_token token, so that it can make various requests. This all works fine.

Now I want to use features of the Facebook Javascript SDK (specifically open the requests dialog), but I do not want the user to be forced to log into Facebook on the client if he just logged into the application using username/password.

**Question**

Having a valid access_token on the server, I want to pass this token to the Facebook javascript SDK, so that no matter how the user logged into my web application, he is now "logged in" to the Facebook account associated with his account, as far as the SDK is concerned.

I have found a few vague examples, but none that explain in detail how to do it entirely.

Currently I am thinking the way to go is passing the token to javascript in FB.Init, but I cannot get it to work:

```
FB.Init({
    authResponse: {
        access_token: <token>,
        expiresIn: <expiry>,
        signedRequest: <what-is-this?>,
        userID: <user>
     },
     ...
});
```

Another example I found, passed the access_token directly to the API call, but this does not seem to work either:

`FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', access_token: <token>, ... ();`

Any ideas?

Comment: There should be no need to pass the access token from the server to the client – when you embed the JS SDK and set `status: true` while doing so, it should automatically recognize a user that has connected to your app before and provide you with an access token client-side. (If it doesn’t do so automatically, then maybe you will need to call `FB.getLoginStatus` explicitly.)

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I am trying to do. What you suggest, implies that the user is either logged onto Facebook in the browser or will be prompted to do so. I want to avoid this. The user has not neccesarily logged into my web app using Facebook at this particular login, but the server has a valid offline access_token from a previous login. I want to use this previously obtained token on the client, instead of bothering the user with logging in.

Comment: Passing the access token while initializing the SDK as you tried is not possible. It is possible to pass the token explicitly when making API calls, yes – but you are not trying to make an API call here, you are trying to invoke the Requests dialog. And that is specifically designed to be actively triggered by the user, to avoid developers misusing this feature in a spammy way. And therefor I am pretty sure it will not work without having an actually logged-in user.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer, and was leaning more and more towards that myself. I was hoping that it somehow was possible. I do not mind that the user gets a "Send request" dialog, but I was hoping I could bypass the login for convenience since the user has already logged in at an earlier point in time. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: The usage scenario is perfectly valid imho, the user shouldn't have to login both server side and client side. The server side access_token really ought to be a proof that the user is already logged in, since it already works with api calls. My guess is that they are just sloppy and lazy like always on Facebook and require the login cookie from facebook.com to be set. Which it won't be when logging in server side. There is no risk of spam in this scenario that I can think of, the user has to click the button either way?